# Dockerfile Build Error: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: docker, dockerfile

```
C:\kafka> docker build Dockerfile
[+] Building 0.0s (1/2)
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 63B                                                                                                                      0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: walk Dockerfile: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Above is an example of the error I am getting and the command run.
My Dockerfile is named "Dockerfile" as I have read on many answers but still no resolve.
My Dockerfile is also within the directory I am in.

Comment: The argument to `docker build` is a _directory_ name, and Docker looks for `Dockerfile` in that directory.  Try _e.g._ `docker build .` to build the current directory.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To build a docker image:

```
cd /path/where/docker_file/lives
docker build .
```

Above is same as:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

You need to specify `Dockerfile` name only if it is not default:

```
cd /path/where/docker_file/lives
docker build -f Dockerfile.modified .
```

Comment: Still getting similar error when I run that command always cancels at .dockerignore but I dont have a docker ignore file

Comment: Add the list of files under `C:\kafka>` and add contents of `Dockerfile` it self. You should be running `C:\kafka>docker build .` assuming that you have proper `C:\kafka\Dockerfile`. Pay attention to the `.`, it should be after `build`.

Comment: I have fixed the issue thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :) don't forget to comment about your solution, if answer was helpful, marking it as answered.